# Why the lag number of an AR model doesn't indicate the number of lags in a plotted ACF?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

In the below image, there are AR models with differing lags.  As far as I know, each autocorrelation function plot has an x-axis that is "number of lags".  Can someone help me understand how there are the same number of observations (lags, in the case of ACF) for each AR model?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your title asks about ACF but you actually display PACFs.

A lag-1 correlation *induces* a lag-2 correlation (and lag-3, 4 etc). Lag-1 and lag-2 correlations induce lag-3 and higher correlations, etc. So actual ACFs for AR models tend to show shrinking (and eventually, geometrically decreasing) correlations across lags.

e.g. for an AR(1), the population correlation at lag 1 is $\phi$, at lag 2 is $\phi^2$ and so on; at lag $k$ the correlation is $\phi^k$.

If you want a display that "cuts off" at the highest AR lag (apart from effects of noise) for a true AR model*, then you want the PACF (or the IACF).

In effect, the PACF removes the impact of the lower-order correlations on the higher order correlations, letting you see what remains after accounting for that.

If you look closely at your PACF plots in the question they do in fact cut off at the required lags. For some reason, the plots include the 0-lag - which is not informative - so the PACF for the AR(1) shows 2 spikes, one at lag 0 and one at lag 1 (and then cuts off to near 0), just as it should.

* in practice, real data don't exactly follow AR models so there's always a decision as to whether the model may be a close enough approximation to be useful for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you -- yep, I realize they were PACFs but the question is more about why there are even those other lags plotted.  I think you answered that part.  But now I supposed I'm confused by the difference between AR(1), AR(2), AR(3), and so on...if AR(1) has any number of lags.  I might be thinking of all of this completely wrong.

Comment: I think I'm honestly confused on the relationship/difference between an autoregressive model and an autocorrelation function.  I thought one used an autoregression to determine autocorrelation in a univariate series (VAR for multivariate).

Comment: You can use them to fit autocorrelated series, but there's not a direct one-to-one correspondence between autocorrelations at lag k and the corresponding k-th coefficients in an autoregression; it's more complicated than that. I suggest reading a good text on basic time series (one that includes ARIMA models). Perhaps https://otexts.com/fpp2/ or perhaps Shumway and Stoffer's book *Time Series: A Data Analysis Approach* https://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsda/  (there are a number other of good options)